# Query and Parse JSON Hive column in Spark using Python

Tags: json, hive, pyspark

I'm trying to query a Hive table using Pyspark.

I have a JSON column in this table and I would to know how to load it correctly in order to parse it.

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hive_context = HiveContext(sc)
query = hive_context.sql("SELECT json_column FROM 
table")
df1 = sqlContext.jsonRDD(query)
df1.first()
```

For now it show the json file but with the mention "*_corrupt_record*".

Comment: Make sure the JSON record is not multi-line with that way.

Comment: @mrsrinivas what do you mean by multi-line?